# Is there a filter for your own questions that you haven't accepted an answer for?

Tags: support, status-completed

Every once in a while, I do a sanity check for my accept rate.

- If I find a question without an acceptable answer, I'll open a bounty.
- If I find a reasonable answer, I'll pick it...

As I have 63 questions, looking for one without accepted answer is a chore. So, there's the question: is there a filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for:

`user:me hasaccepted:0 is:question`

See: [search tips](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/search)

Comment: Great link. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to safe this query somewhere?

Comment: @BaffledCook bookmark it :)